# Wordpress - Dropdown menu issues

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes, dropdown

I'm having trouble organising the top menu on my site.
There are categories in the dropdown menus which work fine, for example "The Details" lead to Contact and About me.

My issue is that when "The Details" is clicked (which it shouldn't really because it's a dropdown menu, but I figure some people might do it anyway), that doesn't lead anywhere but to a "Page not found".

Is there anyway I can put a post that you get redirected to, or just deactivate it so that the only things that are clickable are the items within the dropdown?

I'm sorry if I'm in the wrong, I've really been looking around for answers and I'm guessing it's a pretty easy fix but I'm pulling my hair here.
The website is http://www.mywondermentals.com if you need a look.

Thanks!
V.

Comment: how is the menu created? wp_nav_menu?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your theme is using `wp_nav_menu`. You could try changing that menu item to a Custom Link Item with `#` as URL address :)